# Internal CSS grid borders for uneven lists

Tags: css, grid, border

http://jsfiddle.net/jeepstone/UZejB/

This grid works fine when I have 12 products, or indeed any multiple of the line length (3) but when I have left over items, my borders don't work. I'm after an internal grid that works for any number of items.

If there is only 1 item on the last line then there are bottom or right borders. If there are 2, then the items have only a right border.

Comment: What browser are you working in? In Chrome 21 items 13 or 13 and 14 look fine to me. In FF The borders all appear but the 14th one looks a few pixels too wide. But I couldn't reproduce what you mentioned in either case.

Comment: OK. I've now amended the HTML so that there are 11 boxes, not 12. Look at the last line and you'll see the borders are wrong.

Comment: Sorry, even with 11 boxes it looks totally normal. Here's a screenshot of what I see: http://i.imgur.com/sctXF.png. Can you share a screenshot of what you're seeing, or info on what browser version you're using?

Comment: Sorry! I hit run not update. Check it again http://jsfiddle.net/jeepstone/UZejB/3/

Comment: Ok, I see it now thanks. Let me take a better look.

Answer (score 0):

In your fiddle you have the 'last3' class on the last 3 elements. I'm not sure how you generated this, but if you can generate this you should be able to instead use a modulo to generate a class simply called 'lastrow' that would only go on items in the last row, rather than always the last 3. With this you can easily tell it to display certain borders. I also changed the border top to border bottom so that will guarantee that you will always have a border where you should (for example with 10 items)

**HTML with new classes**

```
<section class="products">
    <article class="product-single  cf">1</article><article class="product-single  cf">2</article><article class="product-single  cf">3</article><article class="product-single  cf">4</article><article class="product-single  cf">5</article><article class="product-single  cf">6</article><article class="product-single  cf">7</article><article class="product-single  cf last3 ">8</article><article class="product-single cf">9</article><article class="product-single lastrow cf">10</article><article class="product-single lastrow cf">11</article></section>​
```

**REVISED CSS**

```
* {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
section.products {
width: 100%;        
}
section.products article.product-single  {
    width: 33.3333%;
    padding: 2%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 260px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
    border-right: 1px solid red;
    position: relative;
}

section.products article.product-single:nth-child(3n) {
    border-right: none;
}

section.products article.lastrow{
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

​

[Here's the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/digthedoug/u2mpP/)